# turn json format String into dataset spark using java

Tags: java, json, dictionary, apache-spark, dataset

Very new to spark...

Suppose that we have a json format String such as following:

```
 String  entry1 = "{\"user_id\":1111,\"account_num\":12345}";
```

how can I read it in to a spark dataset? I understand that dataset can easily read json formatted data from a path as following:

```
SparkSession sparksession = SparkSession.builder()...
Dataset<Row> dataset = sparksession.read().json('path')
```

but how to directly turn the String above into a dataset? Thank you.

Comment: If nobody answers, your next step is to look at the source code for `json()` to see if you can plug in a `java.io.StringReader` somewhere to force it to read from a string instead of from a file.  That will probably be faster than waiting for someone here to answer.

Comment: Thank you@JimGarrison, yes, I am looking at them right now.

Comment: You would think the I/O would be decoupled from the parsing so you could apply it to various input sources, but I couldn't find anything obvious in the API.  If you find a solution please post it as an answer and self-accept it (after the required delay period).  This is a very reasonable question that needs to be on SO.

Answer (score 6):

Update:
Create a list and pass it to createDataset this will give you DataSet then you can convert to your Dataset via spark.read

```
List<String> jsonData = Arrays.asList(
        "{\"user_id\":1111,\"account_num\":12345}");
Dataset<String> anotherPeopleDataset = spark.createDataset(jsonData, Encoders.STRING());
Dataset<Row> anotherPeople = spark.read().json(anotherPeopleDataset);
```

<strike>I have looked into the documentation but couldn't find the read from String. Some of the functions are undocumented.</strike> However Following is a little workaround

```
try {
    String  entry1 = "{\"user_id\":1111,\"account_num\":12345}";
    File file = File.createTempFile("temp",".txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    bw.write(entry1);
    bw.close();
    SparkSession sparksession = SparkSession.builder()...
    Dataset<Row> dataset = sparksession.read().json(file.getAbsolutePath())
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: Thank you Sahil, I tried something similar, but not sure how it will perform in real life when there are tens of thousands of the same operations every second...

Comment: For that I am not sure either. tell me one thing. from where you get the data in String like from database,api request? I don't know much about Spark. it would be great if you can tell

Comment: for now, we get data from both data files and mysql database, and hive... so, we need consistent input for the sparksession part...

Comment: @user6396 I have updated my answer and this way you can convert multiple strings at once